# nodejs - watch directory for changes in background and perform some action

Tags: node.js, background-process, watch, spawn

This might be obvious, however I am struggling to find a solution.

```
// watch.js
var fs = require('fs');

function watch(dir, config) {
  fs.watch(dir, {
    persistent: true,
    recursive: true
  }, (event, filename) => {
    if (filename) {
      console.log(`filename changed: ${filename}`);
      // do something
    }
  });
}

module.exports = watch
```

I want to run this `watch` in background, something like `nohup`, I looked at [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) but still can't figure out the usage.

As per the documentation `child_process.spawn` expects a `command` as the argument.

Any pointer how could I achieve it?

Goal is to watch directory for changes in background and perform some action.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background"? Node.js is asynchronous; it sounds like you just want to call the function.

Comment: Similar to `nohup` I expect to run a `binary` which will return the prompt in terminal and will keep watching the filesystem.

Comment: Then you need to run a new process, with a command line.  (probably `node somefile.js`)

Comment: **Goal is to watch directory for changes in background and perform some action.** - any example?

Comment: Why do you want to do that, isn't fs.watch already async and only the callback is processed in the event loop?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use spawn you can split your *watch* process into its own script and then spawn it from  your main script.  then have the main script watch for output.

this is considering your *watch* function doesn't need to know about anything going on in the calling process.

*watcher.js*

```
var fs = require('fs');

function watch(dir, config) {
  fs.watch(dir, {
    persistent: true,
    recursive: true
  }, function(event, filename) {
    if (filename) {
      console.log("filename changed: " + filename); //to stdout
    }
  });
}

watch('./watchme/');  //<- watching the ./watchme/ directory
```

*main.js*

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const watch = spawn('node', ['watcher.js']);

watch.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("stdout: " + data);
});

watch.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("stderr: " + data);
});

watch.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log("child process exited with code " + code);
});
```

Comment: How do I get the main process to finish, I tried with `options = { detached :true, stdio: ['ignore'] }` & `watch.unref()`

Comment: Oh ok, so you just want to use the main to start the other script.  The stdio option as an array actually has 3 elements which are stdin,stdout,stderr respectivley.  so you should ignore all 3 like this: { detached :true, stdio: ['ignore','ignore','ignore'] }.  You can also just use a String as the stdio options value and that will apply to all 3 so: { detached :true, stdio: 'ignore' }  will do the same thing

Comment: also if you do ignore then the stdout.on and stderr.on handlers will throw an error, so you'll want to remove those if using stdio: 'ignore'

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this? Isn't fs.watch anyway already async and only the callback is run in the single thread?